# Substance Painter: Jagged edges when painting normals

Tags: textures, normal-mapping

[image]

I am painting normals on a normal layer using the Textures tab to make bumps and crevices. But the effect is so jagged. How can I fix this?

INB: Texture Set is already on 4K so it's not a quality issue.

Comment: It looks like the size of the jaggies matches the size of the texel artifacts in the rest of the material, so this looks very much like a resolution limitation. You say the texture set is 4K, but how much area on your model is this 4K stretched across? If you zoom in on a small enough portion of a 4K texture, you'll still end up seeing individual texels.

Comment: I think I understand. UV map is quite bunched up, so possibly that's the issue here.